# Pass method name from property to lambda without arguments

Tags: c#, methods, lambda, delegates, expression

I am trying to achieve the following:

```
this.helper.Verify(i => i.SomeModule.SomeMethod);
```

Where:

- **i** is a known type.
- **SomeModule** is a public property of this type.
- **SomeMethod** is the name of the method (passed as *delegate* I assume).

I would like to be able to **avoid specifying the generic types** in the `Verify` method.

Thats how far I've been able to go:

```
public void Verify<TProp, TResult>(
            Expression<Func<KnownType, TProp>> moduleExpression,
            Expression<Func<TProp, TResult>> methodExpression)
{
    var moduleIdentifier = (moduleExpression.Body as MemberExpression).Member.Name;
    var methodIdentifier = (methodExpression.Body as MethodCallExpression).Method.Name;

    this.Verify(moduleIdentifier, methodIdentifier, state);
}
```

But this forces me to write the argument values for the methodExpression, like:

```
this.helper.Verify(
    i => i.SomeModule,
    m => m.SomeMethod(arg1, arg2));
```

Is there a way to achieve what I am looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I end up with a solution that requires delegates.

I need to analyze an expression that can have multiple arguments, like:

```
i => i.Car.Engine.Intake.Open()
```

I will extract the last two arguments as a "module" and "method":

```
public class ExpressionTools
{
    public string GetLastInstanceName<TProp, TDelegate>(Expression<Func<TProp, TDelegate>> expression)
    {
        var unaryExpression = (UnaryExpression)expression.Body;
        var methodCallExpression = (MethodCallExpression)unaryExpression.Operand;
        var methodInfoExpression = (MemberExpression)methodCallExpression.Arguments.Reverse().Skip(1).First();
        var instanceName = methodInfoExpression.Member.Name;

        return instanceName;
    }

        public string GetMethodName<TProp, TDelegate>(Expression<Func<TProp, TDelegate>> expression)
    {
        var unaryExpression = (UnaryExpression)expression.Body;
        var methodCallExpression = (MethodCallExpression)unaryExpression.Operand;
        var methodInfoExpression = (ConstantExpression)methodCallExpression.Arguments.Last();
        var methodInfo = (MemberInfo)methodInfoExpression.Value;

        return methodInfo.Name;
    }
}
```

### Solution with delegates

A class with generics can be reused since the delegates are not necessary to analyze the expression:

```
public class Verifier
{
    public void Verify<TDelegate>(Expression<Func<KnownType, TDelegate>> methodExpression)
    {
        var tools = new ExpressionTools();
        var moduleName = tools.GetLastInstanceName(methodExpression);
        var methodName = tools.GetMethodName(methodExpression);

        // My logic.
    }
}
```

Now I need to create the delegates, For that I created a file and declared them without a class:

```
namespace Whatever
{
    public delegate void VoidDelegate();
    public delegate void VoidBoolDelegate(bool value);
    // etc...
}
```

Finally, I need to maintain a class that has the same method overloaded with the different delegates.

```
public class FakeExtensions
{
    public static void Verify(
        this Fake fake, 
        Expression<Func<KnownType, VoidDelegate>> methodExpression)
    {
        var tools = new ExpressionTools();
        var facilitator = new Verifier(fake, tools);
        facilitator.Verify(methodExpression);
    }

    public static void Verify(
        this Fake fake, 
        Expression<Func<KnownType, VoidBoolDelegate>> methodExpression)
    {
        var tools = new ExpressionTools();
        var facilitator = new Verifier(fake, tools);
        facilitator.Verify(methodExpression);
    }
}
```

### Alternative solution without delegates

The easiest solution would be to pass a default value for each parameter, but that would express that the values are also verified, which is not the case. I really *dislike* the idea of having something like this:

```
this.helper.Verify(i => i.SomeModule.SomeMethod(0, false, 0.0, null);
```

Since Moq is part of our testing framework, it is possible to use It.IsAny as a value for each parameter of a method call, wich expresses that the values don't matter:

```
this.helper.Verify(i => i.SomeModule.SomeMethod(It.IsAny<int>, It.IsAny<bool>, It.IsAny<double>, It.IsAny<SomeType>);
```

### Why did I choose the delegates solution

I have to verify some calls on a low-level 3rd party API that has methods with up to 100 parameters. I think that the burden of maintaining a delegates list and method overloads pays off in maintainability, readability and ease of use.